# Доступ к локальнуму серверу через wlan и eth по домену

Tags: linux, сеть, raspberry-pi

У меня есть сервер на RPI, к нему должен быть доступ как из WI-FI так и по лану

Я делал точку доступа по [этой](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md) статье

Точка доступа работает и после подключения я могу зайти на gw.wlan и попасть на мой сервер

Кроме действий из статьи я больше не трогал конфиги сети

Что нужно сделать чтоб подключаясь по лану я так же мог использовать gw.wlan?

Comment: роутер дома какой?

Comment: @eri роутера не будет. Сервер будет стоять буквально в поле и питаться от батарей. К нему можно подключится либо по WI-FI, либо напрямую воткнуть эзернет в ноутбук